# what's the practice which I should follow to declare variables that will get a value from the onInit() without marking them with late keyword

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

so I have a `GetxController`, like the following:

```
class ExampleController extends GetxController {
  late TextEditingController textController;   
   @override
   void onInit() {
    textController = TextEditingController();
    super.onInit();
   }      
  }
```

this piece of code will work very fine, but as I know, using the `late` keyword is not recommended use, and removing it, in this case, will cause a dart analyzer null safety lint:

```
Non-nullable instance field 'emailController' must be initialized.
```

Try adding an initializer expression, a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.

so is their better options, or ways to do the same without using late or marking the `TextEditingController()` nullable?

Comment: Seems opinion based. Using late is like promising. I mostly go for nullable. But If i initialize inside initState I use late

Comment: I'm using a dart linter, and it annotates that I shouldn't use a late keyword on that case, so I asked here.

Comment: Ohh, so I should just ignore it on cases like this?

Comment: Sorry cant say because I am not aware of  `GetxController` class

Comment: This is my take on it. If it doesn't make sense for a variable to be null after you consider an object initialized then you shouldn't make the variable nullable, rather you should use `late`. In your example, you can initialize the `TextEditingController` where it's declared, so that's why you're getting a linting error (I think). One advantage that a nullable field has over a late field is that you can check if it has or hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: why are you declaring textediting controllers in onInit() ?

Comment: because I want them to be available only when I inject that controller in the view !